# Drawing a SIMPLE vertical line with g.DrawLine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-3.5

This may appear a silly question to some but it is giving me a headache! I know how to draw a horizontal line in my program like so:

```
 e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Gray, 1), new Point(22, 1100), new Point(782, 1100));
```

But for some reason, I cannot seem to get around displaying a simple vertical line. This is what it currently looks like: (I'm looking at it in Preview using PrintDocument.

[image: d]

I know it is going to be a real simple answer and I have researched.

Comment: What is the problem? If y1 = y2, its horizontal and if x1 = x2 it vertical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be completely missing the point here, but presumably the `new Point(X,Y)` lines there are the coordinates of the line?

That being the case, surely what you want is something like ...

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Gray, 1), new Point(22, 10), new Point(22, 1100));
```

where you keep the X position the same in both points but change the Y?

Comment: I was just totally confused for some reason, but I figured it out and posted an answer which is pretty much like yours.

Comment: I figured it out, as I said, for myself. Nevertheless, due to similarities I tried accepting your answer but it said I had to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Yay! I have found a solution:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Orange,1), 400, 400, 400, 100);
```